# $K$ is the fraction field of $R$, but $R$ is not an order in $K$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

1. Give an example of non-trivial number field $K$ (so $K \not= \mathbb{Q}$) and a proper subring $R$ of $K$ such that $K$ is the fraction field of $R$, but $R$ is not an
   order in $K$.
2. Given that there exist solutions where $K$, $L_1$, $L_2$ are quadratic, give an example of two number fields $L_1$ and $L_2$ contained in a bigger number field $M$ such that $\mathcal{O}_{L_1L_2}\neq \mathcal{O}_{L_1}\mathcal{O}_{L_2}$.